# Ember abort queryParams transition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to capture transitions to run a few checks before carrying on. In **almost** all of my use cases, I can accomplish it just fine.

However, I have one set of links that only change the `queryParams`. When I try `transition.abort()` on this link, I get an error.

Here is my template:

```
{{#link-to (query-params date=nextWeek)}}next{{/link-to}}
```

And, on the route:

```
actions: {
    willTransition (transition) {
      transition.abort();
    }
}
```

The error:

```
transitionByIntent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62857:16
refresh@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62948:14
refresh@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:37404:14
queryParamsDidChange@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:37123:13
triggerEvent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:39417:13
trigger@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:64310:7
fireQueryParamDidChange@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:63092:7
getTransitionByIntent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62785:5
transitionByIntent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62855:16
refresh@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62948:14
refresh@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:37404:14
queryParamsDidChange@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:37123:13
triggerEvent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:39417:13
trigger@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:64310:7
fireQueryParamDidChange@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:63092:7
getTransitionByIntent@https://192.168.1.3/assets/vendor.js:62785:5
```

I truncated the error message. Basically it looks like it is trying over and over and over again to make the transition.

Furthermore, despite the errors, the page does refresh (which it shouldn't) based upon the new parameters.

**QUESTION**

How to capture a transition on JUST a change in the query parameters, so that I can decide to proceed or `abort`?

I know there is the `queryParamsDidChange` hook. I wish there was `queryParamsWillChange`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `do_something` method in the route and call inside willTransition.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    _doSomething() {
        //write your logic and return true if want to stop transition.
    },
    actions: {
        willTransition(transition) {
            //You can write doSomething logic here or you can write function and call
            if (this._doSomething()) {
                transition.abort();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

Note: `queryParamsDidChange` is private method. This implementation can be changed without notifying anytime.

Comment: That is the implementation that I have. The problem is that abort does not actually seem to abort on a link that is unnamed as in my example. I'll try to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: Try it in ember-twiddle.com